# Entity Framework - NullReferenceException in System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.GetOtherEndOfRelationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I get a null reference exception sometimes when i call save changes on dbcontext. This only happens in a few scenarios.

Fails when i do the following.

> entityObject.SomeForeignKeyId= X where X is a integer;

The same code works for

> entityObject.SomeForeignKeyId= Y where Y is a integer and not equal to
>   X;

so as a work around we have been using

> entityObject.SomeForeignKey= Repository.Some.Find(X);
>
> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.  at
>   System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.GetOtherEndOfRelationship(IEntityWrapper
>   wrappedEntity)  at
>   System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.AddRelationshipDetectedByForeignKey(Dictionary`2
>   relationships, Dictionary`2 principalRelationships, EntityKey
>   relatedKey, EntityEntry relatedEntry, RelatedEnd relatedEndFrom)  at
>   System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInForeignKeys()  at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChangesInForeignKeys(IList`1
>   entries)  at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges()

We use EF 4.3

Answer (score 0):

The problem may encountered due to the fact that there is no corresponding FK column(s) on one of the navigation properties. Check all of the related POCO classes and their relationships by matching the PK-FK pairs. On the other hand, you can have a look at the Database Diagrams of your datatables to examine the relations on a schema. Please let me know if it solved the problem or not and post your POCO class definitions here.

Answer (score 0):

It's an answer to and old question, but in case anyone else comes across it:

My issue involved using a JSONPatch approach and patching changes directly onto a EF entity. The patch applied great but i hit this error when I nulled a Reference in a 1-to-many relationship from the many side. For example:

```
public class Foo
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int? MyBar_Id {get; set;}
   public Bar MyBar {get; set;}
}

public class Bar
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public List<Foo> MyFoos {get; set;}
}
```

If i Just loaded Foo as a DynamicProxy and using my JSONPatch ONLY set the `MyBar` property to null, i encountered this error. I noticed however that the behaviour changed significantly when i had inspected the object with the debugger. If i inspected it before applying the patch, when setting `MyBar` to null, `MyBar_Id` was also null and when saving changes it was fine. If I inspected afterwards, then `MyBar_Id` was NOT null and i would hit this error.

My solution was to tweak the JSONPatch process and, before setting a property to null check to see if it already has a value. If it does AND it too is an EF mapped object, retrieve it (forcing lazy initialization) and THEN to use reflection to get all of its own properties. This forces initialization of all of the `Bar` objects properties, loading the FK on both sides and the problem was resolved.

It was one hell of a bug, and the workaround is terrible, but it does solve the issue.